# Split a string in R and assign to a list

Tags: r

I want to split a string and then pass it to a list.

For ex:

```
string <- "hi hello"
```

After splitting, and putting into a list named `l`, then `l[1]` should give me `hi` and `l[2]` should give me `hello`.

Tried hard to search earlier questions, but could not find this.

Comment: This has to be covered numerous times on this site: `l <- strsplit(string, " ")[[1]]` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have it

```
> l <- strsplit(string, " ")[[1]]
[1] "hi"    "hello"
> l[1]
[1] "hi"
> l[2]
[1] "hello"
```

Comment: What is `[[1]]` at the last means?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, `strsplit` is vectorized and returns a `list` the same length as the input vector with the split items within that list item. Since this is a single vector being split, to flatten it into a single vector, you can directly access it with `[[1]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option. Instead of `split`ting, match what you want.

```
> x <- 'hi hello'
> l <- regmatches(x, gregexpr('\\S+', x))[[1]]
> l[1]
## [1] "hi"
> l[2]
## [1] "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the separated strings into separate lists.

```
string <- "hi hello"
l <- lapply(unlist(strsplit(string, split= " ")), FUN = function(x) x)

[[1]]
[1] "hi"

[[2]]
[1] "hello"
```

Comment: Um... why not just `as.list(unlist(strsplit(string, " ")))` if that's the output you think they're after?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, fair enough, little shorter code but same result.  Mind just went to `lapply` but `as.list` is more concise.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Oh what the heck....

To take a totally different approach, since you're splitting on spaces, you can also easily use `scan`:

```
l <- scan(what = "", text = string)
# Read 2 items
l[1]
# [1] "hi"
l[2]
# [1] "hello"
```

Note that if this is what you want, your terminology is off. In R, this is a `vector`. If you wanted a `list`, wrap `scan` with `as.list`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
l = unlist(strsplit(string, ' '))

l[1]
[1] "hi"

l[2]
[1] "hello"
```

Comment: Now these answers are getting out of hand....

Comment: The OP simply wants an object l that gives proper values for l[1] and l[2].